# How to link a button to a tabindex in the same page?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to learn html by myself. I just want to know that is there any way to link a button to a tabindex within that page?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anchors, like:

```
<a href="#el_id">Click</a>
...
<div id="el_id">content</div>
```

Link to element with `tabindex` isn't possible, without JavaScript, of course.